# ASP.NET WebAPI return headers before receiving request body

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api2

I have a scenario where I need to send some headers to the client before receiving the request body.

It would be like using the 100-continue, but I could not figure out how to do this with ASP.NET WebAPI.

Is there a way using the native tools and IIS hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use http method “HEAD”.
Please see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.4

Comment: I was trying to find something that allows me to read the response headers before sending the full body without making two requests, but I think that by using the HEAD method is indeed the correct way.